# Problem with xcode when try to publish a react native app

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native-ios, xcode10

I am currently trying to publish an app based on reactNative, which was first compiled with xcode 9 and now when I try to publish it with xcode 10 it throws me the following error:

```
'__rip' in '__darwin_arm_thread_state64
```

any ideas ?

thanks to everyone!

sorry this is a fully error log message!!

```
no member named '__rip' in '__darwin_arm_thread_state 64'
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the complete error message? Please post some more text of the build log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19839#issuecomment-422390104

Or don't build & run on psychical device -> use XCode Simulator :-)

Comment: Yes, I've been trying that, but it still does not work, I need to compile to send it to the app store, that's my problem

Comment: So you cant compile or you are trying to run it on device? 
Your export fails, if I understand correctly.